# Angular mat-autocomplete shows wrong filtered options

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-autocomplete

When I enter something into input, I have to find all the options that include that substring. The problem is that the filtered values ​​are not displayed correctly.

For example, I have several words: *n, new, need, snow.*

1. When I enter "*n*", autocomplete doesn't show anything (but should show all options).
2. When I enter "*ne*", it shows *n, new, need, snow* (but should show *new, need*).
3. When I enter "*new*", it shows *new, need* (but should show only *new*).
   As if the Search service takes the previous entered value.

My template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<input [formControl]="myForm.get('myInput')" type="text" [matAutocomplete]="myAutocomplete"/>
<mat-autocomplete #myAutocomplete="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of autocompleteItems" [value]="item">
        {{item}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
</form>
```

In my component:

```
public myForm = new FormGroup({myInput: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])});
public autocompleteItems: string[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm.get('myInput').valueChanges
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
        switchMap((inputString: string) => this.mySearchService.search(inputString)))
    .subscribe((foundStrings: string[]) => {
        this.autocompleteItems = foundStrings;
        console.log(this.autocompleteItems);
    });
}
```

P. S. Logs show correct array of strings:

1. Input *n* - *n, new, need, snow*.
2. Input *ne* - *new, need*.
3. Input *new* - *new*.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe [pairwise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/pairwise) into your valueChanges Observable to get the `previous`/`next` values in the subscription, then use `next` for the currentValue

```
public myForm = new FormGroup({
  myInput: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
});
public autocompleteItems: string[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm.get('myInput').valueChanges
    .pipe(pairwise())
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
      switchMap((inputString: string) => this.mySearchService.search(inputString)))
    .subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => {
      this.autocompleteItems = next;
      console.log(this.autocompleteItems);
    });
}
```